# Unable to access notes using microsoft graph api

Tags: office365, onenote, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access graph api to read notes pages, I am getting this error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "40004",
    "message": "The OAuth token provided does not have the necessary scopes to complete the request. Please make sure you are including one of the following scopes: Notes.ReadWrite.All,Notes.Read.All",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "d333a0ee-fe7c-4743-8498-350dc340dd8e",
      "date": "2016-04-27T16:52:22"
    }
  }
}
```

I have added new app to work account and added required delegated permissions to my app. Permission details are as follows.

Resource: Microsoft Graph 
permission Scopes: Read User notebooks

Resource: OneNote
permission Scopes: View one note notebooks, View one note notebooks in your organization.

the endpoint I am using:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/notes/pages

I did not find answer in the same question which is asked previously
[OneNote API - no HTTP Resource found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666882/onenote-api-no-http-resource-found/36882884#36882884)

Answer (score 1):

You could  give the "Read all notebooks that the user can access (preview)" or "
Read and write notebooks that the user can access (preview)" permission to Microsoft Graph:
[image]

In my test , without these permissions , i will get the same error as yours , with any of these permissions ,"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/notes/pages" endpoint works fine, this endpoint needs Notes.ReadWrite.All or Notes.Read.All scope.

Answer (score 0):

this request of your was found to be targeting GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/notes/notebooks

We found the following scopes in the token-
Notes.Create,Notes.Read,Notes.ReadWrite,Notes.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp

but none of the Notes.ReadWrite.All,Notes.Read.All scopes were there.

can you double check on the scopes you assigned?

Comment: As mentioned in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2015/04/30/register-your-application-in-azure-ad/

I have added 
View OneNote notebooks in your organization which should give
Notes.Read.All. 

Can you suggest what I missing ?

Comment: I am directly in touch with the developer.